# Determine the orbits of isometries of the plane on unordered pairs of points

Tags: group-theory, geometry, euclidean-geometry

"Let the group M2 of isometries of the Euclidean plane act on the set S consisting of pairs of unordered points of the plane. Determine the orbits of this action, and for each orbit, the stabilizer group."

I would appreciate some help in understanding what the question is asking!  Does the set S contain *all* points of the plane?  If so, why is the question different from M2 acting on the plane?  If S doesn't contain all points of the plane, then what happens if we apply a translation from M2 which takes a point in S to a point outside S?

Part of the problem is that I'm unfamiliar with the term "unordered".  How would you explicitly write the representation of the set out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set $S$ consists of all unordered *pairs* of points of the plane. That's different from the set of all points on the plane. In symbols: $S = \{\{x,y\} \mid x,y\text{ points}\}$.

The word "unordered" tells us that the pair $(x,y)$ should not be distinguished from the pair $(y,x)$. For that reason I wrote $\{x,y\}$, since $\{x,y\} = \{y,x\}$.

An element of the set $S$ is for example $\{(0,0),(1,0)\}$, which is the pair consisting of the point with the coordinates $(0,0)$ and the point with the coordinates $(1,0)$.